# I want to check validation of special character on key-press or key-up event on a text field which allow space,A-Z,a-z,0-9 only

Tags: javascript

I want to check validation of special character on key-press or key-up event on a text field which allow space,A-Z,a-z,0-9 only.

any idea 
thanks

Comment: Do you want just to check, or remove any character other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a demo of this function in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/ch2jA/):

```
function CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(e){
    e = e || event;
    var matched = (/[a-z]/i).test (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))
    document.getElementById('report').innerHTML = 
            matched ? "" : "Valid input: 'a-z' and/or 'A-Z'"
    return matched;
}
```

To allow digits, change `(/[a-z]/i).test` to `(/[a-z0-9]/i).test`

Comment: what is e here ? and e||event ?can you tell me

Comment: e is the keyboard event. `e || event` means: *take the event from the parameter or if it's not there take the global `event`*. It is for IE < 8, where the event is a global object (`window.event`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good writeup on this exact question:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_160.html

Answer (score 0):

Following funciton snippet will help you achieve this

```
Function AlphaNumericValidation(){
var oneChar = "";

for(var i = 0; i < StringSample.length; i++) {
    oneChar = StringSample.substring(i, i+1);

    if ( (oneChar < "0") || (oneChar > "9" && oneChar < "A") || (oneChar > "Z" && oneChar < "a" ) || (oneChar > "z") )
    {   
        if (isAcceptedChar(oneChar) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```